# How to change color text of Button with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

Is there a way to change the color of a button's text when it is selected?

I tried something like:

```
property myButton : missing value

myButton's setTintColor:(current application's NSColor's cyanColor)
```

But I get the error below:

-[NSButton setTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc865f2d000 (error -10000)

Comment: What kind of button?  Note that `tintColor` is from iOS.

Comment: Recessed Button, or Push Button.

Comment: Those don’t have an alternate title when pressed, only the ones that have a state, such as a checkbox.  Are you just wanting to set the title color?

Comment: Yes, I just want to define the title color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply attributes such as color to button titles, you can use an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring?language=objc), for example:

```
    set buttonTitle to myButton's title -- get current title
    set attrString to current application's NSMutableAttributedString's alloc's initWithString:buttonTitle
    attrString's addAttribute:(current application's NSForegroundColorAttributeName) value:(current application's NSColor's cyanColor) range:{0, buttonTitle's |length|}
    set myButton's attributedTitle to attrString
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm!
Could I do the same to change the color of an NSImageView using NSHomeTemplate?

Comment: An image view is not text, but it _does_ have a `contentTintColor` property if you are using Mojave or later.

Comment: same error: -[NSImageView setcontentTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb6dec71c50 (error -10000)

Comment: Method names are case sensitive - the setter method is capitalized when adding `set`, so the name would be `setContentTintColor:`.